# js closures, get function parameters from global context

Tags: javascript, closures

If i have a closure like the code below, how I can get the 'a' parameter outside the closure. JS engine use scope chain to get to find the value of 'a' when I call the closure, but is there some chance to get the 'a' value from global context?

```
function fn(a){
    return function f(b){
        console.log(a + " " + b);
    }
}
```

BR, Igor

Comment: Why would one need that??!

Comment: Haha, i've waited someone to write that. :D For fun :D i'm playing with closures, so I like to know if that is posible? Maybe eval?

Comment: Dont use eval! And that wont help here. Its just impossible

Comment: Ok, I'm just curious if js have some trick to get the input fn parameters from the main function of the closure. And stop with eval is evil, every second framework is based on eval. still! :)

Comment: I dont think so.

Answer (score 1):

Some trick would be assigning it to the function object:

```
function fn(a){
  function f(b){
    console.log(a + " " + b);
  }
  f.a = a;
  return f;
}
```

So you can do:

```
const result = fn(2);
console.log(result.a, result(2));
```

However a closure is there to encapsulate things. If you don't want that, you should not use a closure.

Comment: Yes, tnx. This is good  one. I forgot, functions are objects, so I can add the parameter as property.  But again is there is some other way directly geting the input parameter from global context, some reference to that memory space where all this variables exists for scope chain.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var count=0;
function add(){
return count+=1;
}
function sub(){
return count-=1;
}
function increment(){
document.getElementById("element").innerHTML=add();
}
function decrement(){
document.getElementById("element").innerHTML=sub();
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="increment()">Increment!!</button>
<button type="button" onclick="decrement()">Decrement!!</button><br><br><br>
<div id="element"><div>
```

Comment: Increment&Decrement Buttons: Closure is an inner function that has access to the out function's variable, it's a scope chain. The closure has 3 scope chains. It has access to its own scope, it has access to the outer function's variable and it has access to the global variable. Not only access function's variables but also the function's parameters as mentioned above.